# Refresh Music Player in lumia 535

Tags: music, storage, nokia-lumia-535

Everytime I add a new song to my phone...either from Bluetooth or Download or others,I get them when I check my files. But unfortunately I need to *switch off* my phone and *on* again so as to get the new song(s) in the song list in the music player. Why MS don't have an option for this? Or may be I dont know if they have.

Answer (score 1):

Please note : 
Music player. load only music folder by Default.its not possible to changes.
so you need to move all song in music folder both(memory card and phone memory). then try it.

My suggestion is use Perfect music player,its working fine and well, and have option to re-scan all music in your phone.so whenever you can add song just re-scan for get the song and load to player

Comment: My new added songs are in the music folder only. So, you dont get it? I want to get those songs in the music library at the same time as it is shown in folders respectively. And I do use the in built music player, both *simple* one and *mix radio* I got. What is this Perfect music player man???

Comment: perfect music player is new one. instance of built in music player its perform well

Comment: Ok thank you...

Comment: @djgharphalia07: no thanks.......

Comment: As your wish :D

Comment: @djgharphalia07: don't hesitate to ask any question. i have more software like perfect player

Comment: Sure Sure :) I will.